# scikit-bio v0.5.2 not working with python 3.5 in miniconda

Tags: skbio

I am trying to run a discrete False Discovery Rate correction on my next gen data. Per the owners code I need to set up the following environment:
conda create -n dsfdr2 python=3.5 numpy scipy jupyter scikit-learn scikit-bio statsmodels (I am using miniconda on a 64-bit Windows 7 system).

However, when I run the command I get the following error:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>
> - python=3.5
> - scikit-bio -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Looking into it further, it appears that the scikit-bio requires python 3.5. The scikit website (https://pypi.org/project/scikit-bio/0.2.3/)says it should be compatible with v3.4+).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
@skbio